# Unable to catch scope_identity through KeyValuePair asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ParamCollOutput= new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
ParamCollOutput.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@MenuID", SqlDbType.Int));
ParamCollOutput.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

but i got a error in `Direction`.`Does not contain a defn for...`.I know its not a valid way to declare but how should i get the value and assign it in `int a`.SP is not a problem.Thanks for a help.

Comment: Direction property is defined in SqlParameter class. You are trying to access the property on wrong object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` does not implement `Direction`.

I think you want to do this...

```
SqlParameterCollection coll = new SqlParameterCollection();
coll.Add(new SqlParameter("@MenuId", 123) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
```